# Modularity of a system in c

Tags: c, module, include, header-files

i have a few libraries which I use in modules of the same system. 
My problem is that when I do #include to the h files, finally in the system it says "undefined reference to ..." different functions of the module which included twice, once in each different module. It is probably because of the double declaration, how do I manage it ?

I have "rialtor.h" in which:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "apartment.h"
#include "offer.h"
```

I have "client.h", in which:

```
 #include <stdbool.h>
    #include "apartment.h"
    #include "offer.h"
```

I have "system.c" in which:

```
#include "rialtor.h"
#include "client.h"
```

Comment: If simply including an additional header in a C source file causes the linker to complain about an undefined reference, when otherwise it does not do so, then you must have one or more function definitions in that header (as opposed to merely function prototypes).  That would be very poor form, but not the root of the problem.  We'll need to see [mcve] to give you a complete answer.

Comment: Note in particular that multiple, compatible *declarations* of the same function or variable are completely acceptable in C.  That is certainly not your problem.  Multiple *definitions* of the same function or variable are not allowed, but that's not what the linker is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking in the wrong place.  An *undefined reference* is a linker error.  You're not including all the needed object files or libraries on the command line that produces your executable.

Comment: are you sure ? because all the libraries are there, and all the header, but I include them twice in some places because of the modularity. 
Cause generally I know it is the linker and the stuff you said, but I definitely include all the needed information

Comment: @KittyT2016, including a header in a C source file just provides declarations.  It does not automagically cause definitions of the declared functions to be located and linked in.